# python sqlite3 creating a DB from excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to create a DB from an excel spreadsheet. I have the below code, the issue is when i run my code my database creates a table for each column. I would like to create a table for each spreadsheet listed in the workbook. sheet names are sheet1 and sheet2.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
filename="script"
con=sqlite3.connect(filename+".db")
wb=pd.read_excel(filename+'.xlsx',sheet_name='sheet1')
for sheet in wb:
wb[sheet].to_sql(sheet,con, index=False)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Comment: You're loading one sheet specifically via `sheetname='sheet1'` use `sheetname=None` to load them all, then loop over that

Comment: I originally tried sheetname=none but get the traceback 
NameError: name 'none' is not defined

Comment: per havlock below and stackoverflow.com/questions/57348149. Updated code to reflect sheet_name vs sheetname to avoid a second error.

Comment: How do you print the output here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Passing `sheetname=None` will give you an OrderedDict with keys of the sheet name and values as dataframes, you then loop over that.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
dfs = pd.read_excel('somefile.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
for table, df in dfs.items():
    df.to_sql(table, db)
```

Comment: Thank you passing sheetname=None is what i was looking for. I originally tried that but was hung up as i was passing "none" instead of "None" rookie mistake i appreciate the help!

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57348149/ sheetname should (now?) be sheet_name, ie with an underscore

Comment: The column names? header or no header?

Comment: Sir after so many year's I'm asking how can we insert into custom table having custom colmuns?

Answer (score 2):

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
filename="script"
con=sqlite3.connect(filename+".db")
wb=pd.ExcelFile(filename+'.xlsx')
for sheet in wb.sheet_names:
        df=pd.read_excel(filename+'.xlsx',sheetname=sheet)
        df.to_sql(sheet,con, index=False,if_exists="replace")
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Get the sheetnames first and then read the sheets and write to sqlite as given above.

Comment: Update: `sheetname = sheet` has changed to `sheet_name = sheet` as sheetname got deprecated as of 2018.