# TypeError with pandas.read_excel

Tags: python, pandas

I can't load the xlsx file

```
import pandas
y=pandas.read_excel("as.xlsx",sheetname=0)
y
```

This is the error message

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-54208838b8e5> in <module>
      1 import pandas
----> 2 y=pandas.read_excel("as.xlsx",sheetname=0)
      3 y

c:\users\lenovo-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    206                 else:
    207                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 208             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    209 
    210         return wrapper

c:\users\lenovo-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skip_footer, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, **kwds)
    304         if arg in kwds:
    305             raise TypeError(
--> 306                 "read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument " "`{}`".format(arg)
    307             )
    308 

TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument `sheetname`
```

Comment: The correct argument is `sheet_name` - note the underscore. I'm voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @DavidW.  This is not a typo, but arises from running old code.  The parameter `sheetname` was depreciated and then replaced with `sheet_name` in 2018. See [Github issue #20920](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20920)

Comment: @mjfwest I didn't know that - that's a useful detail

Answer (score 30):

You have  a syntax error

Try

```
y=pandas.read_excel("as.xlsx",sheet_name=0)
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that this "sheet_name" could be language dependent. The argument is also positional, so you can just drop "sheet_name" and write:

```py
y=pandas.read_excel("as.xlsx",0)
```

I have tried version Pandas 1.0.5 and xlrd 1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error. Should be:

```
sheet_name = 'xxx'
```

Comment: how is this different than the other answers already posted?

Answer (score -1):

install `xlrd` from command prompt using below:

1. `conda install xlrd`
2. `pip install xlrd`

It is referred to as `Sheetname`

Comment: OP's problem was caused just by a simple typo, I don't think this answer is helpful here. You might want to clarify why you think this is helpful by editing it.