# Read Sharepoint Excel File in Python - Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sharepoint, office365

I am having trouble reading a SharePoint excel file using Python Pandas and Office 365.
It is outputting "Authentication Successful" but has a few errors stating:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/gfgdfg/Try.py", line 28, in <module> df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, sheetname = None) File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper return func(*args, **kwargs) TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sheetname'`

My full Code is:

````
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://dfsdfksdfhk.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/dkfjsldkfjldjfC4IT3'
username = 'email@outlook.com'
password = 'mypassword'

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
 ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
 web = ctx.web
 ctx.load(web)
 ctx.execute_query()
 print("Authentication successful")

response = File.open_binary(ctx, url)

#save data to BytesIO stream
bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0) #set file object to start

#read excel file and each sheet into pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, sheetname = None)
print(df)```
````

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered here [TypeError with pandas.read_excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57348149/typeerror-with-pandas-read-excel). All in all, just replace `sheetname`  with `sheet_name` in your  code. Should work well.