# Is there a way to do a Select statement like SQL in Excel using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

Given this excel sheet:
[Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS3CD.png)

Lets say the SQL Select statement looks like this:

```
Select Status from sheet where name = "John Doe" and age = 20
```

And return the Status value for the line that matches the name/age
The excel can have more then 1 row also.

Also I've added a the copy paste from excel, but it pasted a picture, i m not sure how to share the actual excel content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method. Something like the below should do the job:

```
>>> df

           Name  Age  Height       Status
0      John Doe   20     180  Not Married
1  Jhonny Dolly   20     170      Married

>>> df.query('Name == "John Doe" and Age == 20')

       Name  Age  Height       Status
0  John Doe   20     180  Not Married

>>> df.query('Name == "John Doe" and Age == 20')[['Status']]

        Status
0  Not Married
```

Comment: This seems neet, I've tried but i m gettin an odd response, or how do I acces the return of the query method?

if I print `print(df.query('Name == "John doe" and Age == 20'))`

It displays:

`Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name, Age, Height, Status]
Index: []`

Also the excel file is not empty and i had to use `engine='openpyxl'` to open the excel file, gave me an error bcs of xlsx extension

Comment: I have mistyped Doe with lowercase. Try changing as per the above example (it is case sensitive)

Comment: Indeed it worked thank you!
One more thing tho, Can the result from query be converted into a dictionary?
Lets say: `{Name': 'John Doe', 'Age': 20, 'Height': 180, 'Status': 'Not Married'} ?

Comment: Yes. Try this: `df.query('Name == "John Doe" and Age == 20').to_dict(orient='records')`

Comment: you're too kind haha, thank you! It indeed worked!

Answer (score 3):

First, load your excel file:

```
df = pd.read_excel("myfile.xlsx")
```

Now you have a dataframe:

```
>>> df
           Name  Age  Height       Status
0      John Doe   20     180  Not Married
1  Jhonny Dolly   20     170      Married
```

You can make request on it:

```
>>> df.loc[(df["Name"] == "John Doe") & (df["Age"] == 20), "Status"]
0    Not Married
Name: Status, dtype: object
```

In a SQL fashion:

```
name = "John Doe"
age = 20
print(df.query('Name == @name and Age == @age')["Status"])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure SQL requests to query your Excel file, you will first need to convert it to a database. The simplest solution is `sqlite` as it's part of Python standard library and does not require setting up a DBMS, combined with `pandas`. You can find an exemple in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46814794/8237838).

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
dfs = pd.read_excel('somefile.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
for table, df in dfs.items():
    df.to_sql(table, db)
```

Comment: Will this not eat alot of RAM tho, if the excel is 1k+ lines or so?
Still neet solution, thank you, will explore it!